# Carousel not displaying when using Polylang plugin

Tags: wordpress, carousel, polylang

I have used Polylang plugin for my Wordpress site which is having 2 languages English & Arabic. I have a carousel in one page which is working perfectly in english page. The same carousel on Arabic page is not visible. Only the navigation arrows are visible.

I tried by disabling the plugins and found that when disabling Polylang plugin the carousel is working in both the pages.

How to rectify this issue?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add direction: ltr in carousel main container

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we add the direction: ltr; to the main container of carousel,  items are appearing like the same in english page. Ideally it should be aligned rtl. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to Additional CSS to solve the problem

```
.owl-carousel:lang(ar) .owl-item,
.owl-wrapper {
direction: rtl;
}
.owl-carousel:lang(ar) { direction: ltr !important; }
.owl-carousel:lang(fa) .owl-item,
.owl-wrapper {
direction: rtl;
}
.owl-carousel:lang(fa) { direction: ltr !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to translate the media to the second language or deactivate the media from the `Polylang` plugin settings, and the carousel will display correctly after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).